# Pass an array to a servlet which returns by jquery multi-select on button click

Tags: jquery, arrays, servlets, multi-select

I have used one of jQuery Multi-select which was free on [this site](http://akibjorklund.com/code/multiselectable).

However I can retrieve the selected values using

```
$('#selectednames').val()
```

as an array, now i need to pass that array as a POST value to a servlet. How can i do that? Please suggest me a way.

Comment: convert the array to a list and send it as a post param under the name "selectednames"

Comment: @ Kevin B, Please can you tell me how?